# Adding objects to an array overwrites instead of adds

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static Person[] read() {
    Person[] array = null;
    try{
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("personnel.csv"));
        int number = Integer.parseInt(file.readLine());
        array = new Person[number];
        String line = file.readLine();
        int i = 0;
        while (line!= null){
            String[] ray = line.split(",");
            ray[1] = ray[1].replace("-", "");
            for(int q=0; q<array.length;q++){System.out.println(array[q]);}
            array[i] = new Person(ray[0], Integer.parseInt(ray[2]), Integer.parseInt(ray[1]));
        //  System.out.println(array[0]);
            line = file.readLine();
            i++;
        }

        file.close();   

    }

        catch (IOException er) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find file personnel.csv");
        }
    return array;}
```

I am reading from a file formatted like this:

```
3
Houser,911-11-1111,1021970
Johnson,222-99-2222,3041948
Aimes,242-25-2332,6041968
```

The issue is that when the code is run, instead of just adding the new Person object to the next spot in the array, it adds it and also overwrites any previous objects in the array.

Running the code as it is, the print statement in the for loop gives me the following output:

```
null
null
null
Houser 1021970 911111111
null
null
Johnson 3041948 222992222
Johnson 3041948 222992222
null
```

I did change one thing to try and fix it, but that was just I had a variable p set and set array[i] to p instead of making it a new Person directly like I am now. I tried printing the person each time and it seemed fine.

Been working at this for a couple of days now, thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Check the scope of your while loop?

Comment: Can you show your Person class? Perhaps it has static members.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thank you so much, I guess my obvious lack of knowledge of what static is has now started causing problems. I'll have to look into it and try to start understanding it better.